# Does a custom trace listener have to be in an assembly to be used?

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

I want to use a custom trace listener for logging but I do not want to create it within a .dll file. Is there a way to configure my enterprise library configuration to use my custom trace listener from a .cs file?

I am using the code on this site http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2006/04/06/unittestyourenterpriselibrarylogginglogic.aspx

as a reference. I notice some of the key methods, like GetLogEntries(), are "internal" so they wouldn't work outside of the .dll file.

Answer (score 1):

Assemblies are the basic unit of deployment so at some point your code (.cs) needs to be within a .DLL or .EXE.  You might be able to use a .cs file in an ASP.NET web site and rely on the runtime to compile your code  (into an assembly) but I'm not sure what that buys you.

The link you posted is a trace listener that is intended to be used for unit testing.  The internal methods are static and are only there for unit testing purposes and are not used by Enterprise Library for performing logging.